# ggplot, conditional fill geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, conditional-statements, geom-point

I am looking for a way to fill geom_point if it meets a condition

Example:

```
mydata <- tibble(x_var = 1:5, 
                 y_var = runif(5), 
                 category_a = c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes'),
                 category_b = c('down', 'up', 'up', 'down', 'down')
                 )

ggplot(mydata,
       aes(x = x_var,
           y = y_var,
           color = category_a,
           )
       ) + 
  geom_point(shape = 21,
             size = 5,
             stroke = 2
             )
```

[image: Plot]

I want to fill in the points that meet the condition `category_b == 'down'` with the same color as `category_a` and leave the rest without filling, how can I do that?
Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternative approach can be the usage of to specific shapes and assign them manually. A nice side effect is a more descriptive legend:

```
mydata <- tibble(x_var = 1:5, 
                 y_var = runif(5), 
                 category_a = c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes'),
                 category_b = c('down', 'up', 'up', 'down', 'down'))

# choose circle and dot shapes
shps <- c(1, 16)


ggplot(mydata, aes(x = x_var, y =  y_var, color = category_a, shape= category_b)) +
    geom_point(size = 5, stroke = 2) + 
    # add manually choosen shapes and colors
    scale_shape_manual(values=shapes)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add your fill-condition inside the `fill` argument. And add the transparent color with `scale_fill_discrete`.

**Code**

```
mydata <- tibble(x_var = 1:5, 
                 y_var = runif(5), 
                 category_a = c('yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'yes'),
                 category_b = c('down', 'up', 'up', 'down', 'down')
)

ggplot(mydata,
       aes(x = x_var,
           y = y_var,
           color = category_a,
           fill = ifelse(category_b == "down", category_a, NA)
       )
) + 
  geom_point(size = 5,
             shape = 21,
             stroke = 2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(na.value = "transparent") +
  guides(fill = FALSE)
```

**Plot**
[image]